# How to get the root element in Moxy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am trying to create an xml by analyzing an xsd using Moxy. I will not be aware of how the xsd looks like.
 The xsd will be provided on the fly. Using Moxy I am able to load the xsd and print details of all the XmlDescriptors. My question is, how to identify the root element.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having xsd, any global type can be root element of xml document. For such global type, use method

```
org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLDescriptor#getDefaultRootElement
```

to get name of root element.